# Linking to an element with an ID not working if linked outside the website

Tags: html

I am trying to set up my site so that the site behaves like a Wikipedia page, where you can link to specific sections and once the link is clicked it takes you to those sections.

I have the Table of Contents set up on each page and if you are already on the page and click the anchor link it does take you to the right section.

However, if I share the link with someone else, the link does not take them to the correct section and just loads the page as if it was a link directly to that page.

I have a live example that you can use to help me troubleshoot.

This link: https://www.bamapolitics.com/alabama/#Alabama_Statewide_Officials should take you to the Alabama Statewide Officials heading but if clicked just loads the page as normal. However, if you click the same link from the Table of Contents area, it does scroll to it.

Any ideas on what I am missing here? This is a very important part of my site as it helps to get people directly to the information that they are requesting on the pages across the site.

Edit: The code is simple. I already explained this. This is the only code on the page. Then the link above is what should work with this.

```html
<header><h2 class="p-1 mt-3 alert alert-info rounded-0"><span id="Alabama_Statewide_Officials">Alabama Statewide Officials</span></h2></header>
```

Video of what happens: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AqlOvyPazAj63kiZofUEWPNUcH3B?e=uNDQtf

Comment: works for me, The anchor loads the page to the element iwth the ID. Just as the anchor is supposed to work. However you should alro provide your code if you actually need trouble shooting.

Comment: The code is simple. I simply have a <span> with an ID attached to it inside the <hx> tags. All the code is visible in that pages source. I am not using any JavaScript. For some reason it is not working for me when I click the above link in Microsoft Edge on Windows 10. Maybe it is something on my end.

Comment: use an actual code snippet (Ctrl + M) an edit your question rather then posting a vague and broad explanation as comment of how your code looks like.

Comment: I updated the post with the only code I am using. There was nothing broad or vague about a simple span with an id inside an hx tag. That is exactly what the code is.

Comment: @tacoshy When i follow the link the page doesn't scroll to the anchor id...

Comment: it doesnt scoll down, it starts there. What browser are you using?

Comment: I have tried it with Edge and on Chrome mobile Android and the link does not go to the section at all. What browser is working for you?

Comment: Please try [this wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia#Community) and tell me, if you are taken to the Community section.

Comment: Works for me on FireFox Desktop 87.0, only I don't see scroll effect when not going to the section from the table of contents - see my answer

Comment: @Programmer yes that link works.

Comment: @Programmer Here is a video showing what happens on my end. https://1drv.ms/v/s!AqlOvyPazAj63kiZofUEWPNUcH3B?e=uNDQtf

Comment: Well that's really ___really___ weird … I literally ran out of ideas on this …

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce that the page does not go to the section. It does go to the specified section, but when directly pasting the link with the ID, I don't see a scroll effect, which I do see when going to the section from the table of contents. The simple answer for that is that the `a` element enclosing the `span#alabama_statewide_officials` has an event listener for the `click` event as follows:

```js
function(t) {
  t.preventDefault();
  var e = this.getAttribute("href"),
    c = e.substring(1),
    d = a(c);
  d && (e !== document.location.hash && (i.onComplete = function(t, e) {
    var i, n, o, l, a, r, s;
    d.setAttribute("id", ""), i = c, n = t, o = e, (s = document.createElement("a")).setAttribute("id", i), s.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;visibility:hidden;left:" + n + "px;top:" + o + "px;"), l = document.body, a = s, l.prepend ? l.prepend(a) : l.insertBefore(a, l.firstChild), document.location.hash = i, (r = s).remove ? r.remove() : r.parentNode.removeChild(r), d.setAttribute("id", c)
  }), u.scrollTo(d, i))
}
```

You can clearly see the `u.scrollTo(d, i))` on the second-last line. That function gets triggered when you click the link in the table of contents. But when you directly paste in the link and go to the site, the function doesn't get triggered, so you don't have the scroll effect.